# Migrate a fileserver that hosts home folders to a new domain - where users use offline files

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, migration

We are about to migate a fileserver from one domain to another.
The problem is that the fileserver hosts home folders, and all users are using offline files by default. The users are already migrated to the target domain. There is an temporary trust between the two domains for now.

Is there any way I can migrate the server to the new domain without losing the references to all the users files, or how should we approach this issue?

The tool that we will use to migrate the server is Quest.

Comment: then call Quest and get your tech support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there was no issue with the offline files regarding the server migration itself. It all went well without any loss access to data.